# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wanting to insert data or to populate a table with new data and have used the insert into command on its own as well as insert into with the columns and values underneath but keep getting the error in the title.

```sql
INSERT INTO A2_FILM (FILM_NO, FILM_NAME, CLASSIFICATION, DURATION, DESCRIPTION, YEAR_RELEASED)
VALUES (00948371, 'Lightyear', 'U', 105, 'Legendary space ranger Buzz Lightyear embarks on an intergalactic adventure alongside ambitious recruits Izzy, Mo, Darby, and his robot companion, Sox.', TO DATE('2022', 'YYYY'));
```

Comment: you are missing an `_` in `TO_DATE`. Also, you will be inserting the first of july (2022-07-01) by doing it like that.

Comment: Thanks, missed that. I am aware that it will be 1st july but the rest of the table is like that and my task is to add new data in the same format so I will not be changing it. Unfortunately my problem still persists.

Comment: Which is the datatype for YEAR_RELEASED column? DATE or NUMBER?

Comment: The data type is 'DATE'

Comment: @EdwinR what it should be the populated value?  YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: @HRK If I go to the year released column in the data tab of the table some of the previous ones are displayed as 01-jul-34 /33/80, etc..

Comment: *"my task is to add new data in the same format so I will not be changing it."* A `date` has no format until you display it, and it always contains year, month, day and time to the second. To avoid storing random months you might as well standardise on 1st January, e.g. `date '2022-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle 19c and SqlDeveloper 21 i not received any error:

```
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------
 FILM_NO                                                        NUMBER(12)
 FILM_NAME                                                      VARCHAR2(100)
 CLASSIFICATION                                                 CHAR(1)
 DURATION                                                       NUMBER(5)
 DESCRIPTION                                                    VARCHAR2(1000)
 YEAR_RELEASED                                                  DATE


INSERT INTO A2_FILM (FILM_NO, FILM_NAME, CLASSIFICATION, DURATION, DESCRIPTION, YEAR_RELEASED)
VALUES (00948371, 
        'Lightyear', 
        'U', 
        105, 
        'Legendary space ranger Buzz Lightyear embarks on an intergalactic adventure alongside ambitious recruits Izzy, Mo, Darby, and his robot companion, Sox.', 
        TO_DATE('2022', 'YYYY')
       );
   
1 row inserted.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the populated value in YEAR_RELEASED column has to equal to YYYY, it looks like you have to  change the datatype to NUMBER. Otherwise if you execute `INSEERT INTO` TO_DATE('2022', 'YYYY') will return DD-MM-YYYY which will be equal to SYSDATE, i.e. in this case the return value is 01-07-2022.

If you change the datatype to NUMBER for YEAR_RELEASED column you can use `EXTRACT()` and try this one:

```
INSERT INTO A2_FILM (FILM_NO, FILM_NAME, CLASSIFICATION, DURATION, DESCRIPTION, YEAR_RELEASED) VALUES (00948371, 'Lightyear', 'U', 105, 'Legendary space ranger Buzz Lightyear embarks on an intergalactic adventure alongside ambitious recruits Izzy, Mo, Darby, and his robot companion, Sox.', EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE('2022-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')));
```

> db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91ba7c0f3117bd6cfc814656a896856e

If the populated value has to be equal to DD-MM-YYYY you can use :

```
INSERT INTO A2_FILM (FILM_NO, FILM_NAME, CLASSIFICATION, DURATION, DESCRIPTION, YEAR_RELEASED) VALUES (00948371, 'Lightyear', 'U', 105, 'Legendary space ranger Buzz Lightyear embarks on an intergalactic adventure alongside ambitious recruits Izzy, Mo, Darby, and his robot companion, Sox.', TO_DATE('2022', 'YYYY'));
```

> db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=41aac71840efc45eaa62e9db42fb75c5